# Switching 2 JBL Flip 4 speakers to stereo on Linux (and macOS)

Tags: linux, bluetooth, reverse-engineering

I want to use 2 JBL Flip 4 bluetooth speakers in stereo mode, which is one of 2 operating modes of the JBL Connect+ protocol.

There is a JBL smartphone app that can be used for this. However, if I want to use the speakers for playback from a PC, this is not an option. The setting does not persist, and the default operating mode of the Connect+ feature is mono.

Is there any reverse-engineering work regarding the JBL Connect+ protocol and its usage?

Regards,
Tino

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found the source for an Android app that can control JBL bluetooth speakers using Connect+.


https://github.com/pembem22/connect-plus


It looks like all I need to do is to send the correct characteristics payload to the device. I'll try to get this working using bettercap.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the source for connect-plus, I managed to switch the devices to stereo playback using gatttool in Linux:

char-write-req 0x000f aa1503004601

The last byte 01 means left, 02 means right.

The above command is for an interactive session in gatttool.

This command does the same with one invocation and no interactivity:

`sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b <device MAC> --char-write-req -a 0x000f -n aa1503004601`

You need to enable Connect+ mode on both speakers before you run the command. I also had the impression that the channel setting might get lost if the playback stops.

For macOS, this can be done using the bleak Python module and a small script. You need to adjust the ADDRESS (MAC and UUID) to your device.

````
import asyncio
import platform

from bleak import BleakClient

CHARACTERISTIC = "65786365-6c70-6f69-6e74-2e636f6d0002"

ADDRESS = (
    "99:99:99:99:99:99"
    if platform.system() != "Darwin"
    else "AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE"
)


async def main(address: str):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        await client.write_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC, bytearray([0xaa, 0x15, 0x03, 0x00, 0x46, 0x01]), True)
        print("Switched to left channel")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ADDRESS))```
````